# document() function for a file on another computer/server

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I understand the use of document() as follows.

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('path\to\docuemnt.xml')/RootElement/Element"/>
```

And this has to be a relative path to the parent XSL file. But what if I need to reference a file which is hosted on another server on the local network? I've tried such things as.

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('\\servername\path\to\document.xml')/RootElement/Element"/>
```

But this throws an error, because it looks in

```
C:\path\to\xsl\\servername\path\to\document.xml
```

Which of course doesn't exist.

Comment: The answer will be dependant on your XSLT processor, the operating system and the file system. As a rule of thumb, you can probably safely use the file:: protocol . Also whether or not your XSLT processor is catalog aware may also affect the outcome. Please tell us about your context (XSLT processor etc.)

Comment: For example, on the Saxon processor, you can reference any file with the standard file:: protocol, but only if you use short file-name form. If you use long file-names, Saxon will not find the file.

Comment: As an alternative to the file protocol, if the file is available via http, you can specify it's http protocol form URI.

Comment: Thanks Sean,

We do have http locations for these files but to no avail.

I'm using Saxon6.5.5 transformer and the PrincePDF generation.

I shall have a look for Saxon documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution only relates to the Saxon-HE 9.4.0.3N XSLT processor, in the console application form, on Windows 7.

In my experimentation, I found that the document() function will accept file names or URIs. However I would avoid filenames because they need to be short-form. If you use long-form, the file-name will be rejected.

Suppose your document is ...

```
c:\path\to\document.xml
```

on server 'servername' which is mapped to drive 'j'.

To form a URI from this use as the document() parameter value...

```
file:///j:/path/to/document.xml
```

In relation to the URI, I was mistaken about Saxon not accepting long-form. This only applies to filenames. However, there are a number of gotchas...

1. Note the forward slashes. Backslashes will not work.
2. I have not found a way to build a workable file: URI with just UNC names. You need to make a drive mapping to a letter.
3. Any failure to open the document for any reason will be reported as the same error. With file system, there are so many things that can go wrong, that if you can't open the file, it is not safe to assume that the URI is wrong. There could be many mundane reasons why a file cannot be opened at a particular time.
4. Beware of firewall issues. These play a role.
5. Many text editors, such as NotePad++ assume, in the absence of a BOM and not encoded in one of the two UTF-16 encodings, that a text file is encoded in the system code-page. Saxon will make the default assumption that the file is encoded in UTF-8 so if you have a character that looks like this in NotePad++ (ä) with my code-page, Saxon will spit the dummy, and report that it is unable to open the file. (Aside: I'm not sure what my code-page is. My o/s is Win7 and the Current system locale is English (Australia). It is the system local that determines the system code-page). The reason why Saxon will not open the document is that the (ä) encoded in some code-page results in a sequence of bytes which is not a valid UTF-8 sequence.
6. URI paths which are not URL paths are not supported by the underlying operating system. Saxon may well truthfully say that it supports URIs in relation to the document() function, but that doesn't boil any cabbages, because in practice, you can't use them. - Well at least not on the windows family of o/s.
7. Please ignore the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the file protocol. The form of URL suggested on that page (with the | character etc) is not accepted by the Saxon document() function. Use the form that I have suggested above. I have tested it and it works.

Comment: boil any cabbages? Is that an Aussieism? :-)

Comment: A good article on the mapping of Windows file names to URIs is given here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/12/06/file-uris-in-windows.aspx. However, the mappings are not standardized, and you can't assume that Java will do it the same way as (say) .NET.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of document() is incorrect. It expects a URI, not a filename.

Comment: Thanks, 

    <xsl:value-of select="document('http://localhost/blah.xml')"/>

Works. Suppose I'll have to arrange for the files to be available at a http:// accessible location.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an HTTP URI, a file: URI will work fine with all processors I know of. (The actual set of protocols accepted is implementation-defined, for example some processors might accept ftp and others won't)