# Issues with document('file:xxxx') selection

Tags: xslt-1.0

In a previous post I asked [how to use 2 or more xlm files as input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758481/how-to-use-two-or-more-xml-files-in-one-xsl-document) and I got it to work based on the suggested replies when pulling the files from a localhost share.

However when I replace the localhost on a share on a remote host, the files aren't retrieved although I can access them fine on the remote machine under windows.

This is the code I use that works:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file://LocalHost/DialStats/InboundStats.xml')" mode="my-mode">
   <!-- pass some parameters -->
 </xsl:apply-templates>
```

When I however change that to this then it suddenly fails:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('file://REG6699SQL01/DialStats/InboundStats.xml')" mode="my-mode"> 
  <!-- pass some parameters -->
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I've also tried to add a drive share to my local machine like this:
    net use v: \REG6699SQL01\DialStats /USER:

this results in the processing to stop with an error stating that the network path can't be found?

Then I replaced the code to this:

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="document('file:///V:/InboundStats.xml')" mode="my-mode">
   <!-- pass some parameters -->
 </xsl:apply-templates>
```

Which does not cause an error but the result is not as expected, it seems as if the file is blank.

Does any one has ideas as to how this could be resolved or troubleshooted?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: possible duplicate, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348024/document-function-for-a-file-on-another-computer-server

Comment: That post did not help me in the slightest to resolve the issue. 
I use URI's and they are valid and still I have an error. I tried all suggestions in there and still no solution. This is not a duplicate and I don't use Saxon either. I use Visual Studio and it also happens in the IE translation.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I use Visual Studio to develop and the processing is done by a proprietary product that uses IE6 as engine